# Difference between m_flow_start and m_flow in ´´initialize´´ section for Valve - Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have a valve in Modelica which has m_flow_start(Guess value of m_flow) and m_flow as initializion value . I can`t understand what is the difference between these values. Could you explain the difference between them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general if you have a parameter `m_flow_start` (or similarly) it means that the model contains

```
Medium.MassFlowRate m_flow(start=m_flow_start ... );
```

The initialization value for `m_flow` is also called `m_flow.start` and is as normally as default equal to `m_flow_start`.

So if you set (or have set) the initialization value of `m_flow` the parameter `m_flow_start` normally becomes meaningless.

So, the procedure is:

1. If `m_flow.start` (initialization value of `m_flow`) is set, you should modify that and ignore `m_flow_start`.
2. Otherwise set `m_flow_start`, and don't modify `m_flow.start` - possibly unless you are changing parameters after translation.

Clearly this is confusing, and for Modelica.Mechanics the models are changed to remove those extra `_start` variables.

Note that in a valve m_flow is normally not a state, so any value is just a guess-value. If you set fixed=true for m_flow it becomes a fixed start-value, but then the initialization is more complicated.